# Como puedo copiar y pegar informacion en un template de excel (que ya esta formulado y todo) mediante Python con Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Tengo un template en excel que ya esta formulado listo para que en cuanto peguen la información este calcule todo, mi duda es como puedo copiar la informacion que filtro de otro excel con Pandas y que del dataframe resultante lo copie en la hoja del Template sin que me borre todo el formato y me calcule las columnas formuladas.

Este es el df que quiero copiar a una hoja de un archivo ya existente:

```
df2 = pd.read_excel("Rep de coberturas.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1') 
pc = df2[df2.UBICACIÓN.str.contains('PC')] 
print(pc.head()) 
df = pd.read_excel("TEMPLATE Balance Planta.xlsx",sheet_name='RRP4 Prod')
```

"PC es el df filtrado que quiero copiar al excel existente"

"df es el archivo al cual quiero copiar la información en la hoja
RRP4 Prod"

Comment: No estoy seguro si pandas tiene una función asi

Comment: entiendo, hmm y abra manera de sobre escribir en un archivo de Excel conservando las demás hojas e información? Porque al momento de pegar dicha información me borra todo lo demás

Comment: Si se puede hacer eso

Comment: sabras como? Lo e intentado de diferentes maneras y no me queda

Comment: Había hecho una respuesta, la estoy buscando, en caso de no encontrarla te daré una

Comment: Gracias! Me ayudara mucho guiarme con tu ayuda

Comment: No lo encontré :(, daré una respuesta pero puedes agregar cuales son tus dataframes?

Comment: Este es el df que quiero copiar a una hoja de un archivo ya existente:

df2 = pd.read_excel("Rep de coberturas.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
# pc = df2[df2['UBICACIÓN'] == 'PC01']
pc = df2[df2.UBICACIÓN.str.contains('PC')]
print(pc.head())

PC es el df filtrado que quiero copiar al excel existente

Comment: Colocalo en tu pregunta >_<

Comment: ya bro, lo siento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de haber las operaciones necesarias con tu *DataFrame*, al querer guardarlo los datos se sobrescribirán, para evitar eso se puede especificar el modo en que pandas hará el guardado del archivo, pero el método `to_excel()` no permite el parametro `mode` así que tendremos que usar otro método que es `ExcelWriter` esto especificando el atributo `mode`. Este atributo tiene los mismo modos que la función `open()` nativa de python, por defecto es `w` que significa que solo escribirá, para añadir información se tiene que especificarlo con modo `a` (append)

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('archivo.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:  
    df.to_excel(writer)
```

Esto agregará los datos, pero también incluirá los headers y tendrás cabeceras duplicadas, pare evitar eso también debemos especificar los si queremos escribir los headers. Si tu archivo Excel siempre existe lo puedes hacer así:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('archivo.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:  
    df.to_excel(writer, header=False)
```

En caso tu archivo se cree en la ejecución del programa o esté vacio, deberás de hacer esto:

```py
import os
ruta = "ruta/archivo.xlsx"
with pd.ExecelWriter(ruta, mode ="a") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, header= not (os.path.isfile(ruta) and os.stat(ruta).st_size !=0))
```

El `os.path.isfile(ruta)` comprueba que exista el archivo y `os.stat(ruta).st_size!=0` comprueba que el archivo no esté vacío (ósea que tenga tamaño)

Comment: Hermano ya le intente como me dijiste y me da este error                       
   TypeError: to_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'

Comment: Me había olvidado que no existe ese parámetro, ahora edito la respuesta

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: Listo amigo, he editado la respuesta

Comment: gracias bro! Me sirvió mucho tu ayuda!

Comment: De nada, recuerda aceptar la respuesta si resolvió tu duda