# Datos scrapeados toman formato incorrecto cuando se vuelcan a excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Estoy scrapeando unas paginas web con python y volcando los datos diariamente en un archivo de Excel usando openpyxl. El problema es que en excel, los datos, que deberían ser números, me aparecen con un signo de advertencia con la leyenda:

> "Numbers formated as text or preceded by an apostrophe"

Y cuando intento graficarlos, no los toma como valores. Tampoco me deja modificar la cantidad de espacios luego de la coma. Probé con deshabilitar la alerta de error y configurarlo como numero y aunque logro que deje de aparecer el signo de advertencia, sigue sin funcionar en el gráfico.

Intenté también con el botón de "text to columns" y funciona perfecto pero el problema es que cuando cargo un nuevo dato se incorpora con la advertencia, y no tendria sentido automatizar todo y tener que entrar diariamente a cambiar eso, necesitaria alguna solución permanente.

El código en python para escribir el archivo es:

```
wb = load_workbook("G:\Mi unidad\Archivo_prueba.xlsx") ws = wb.worksheets[0]

#Datos valores_tc = [
    [d4, valor_blue, valor_mep, valor_ccl],
    ]

for i in valores_tc:
    ws.append(i)

wb.save("G:\Mi unidad\Archivo_prueba.xlsx")
```

Y tanto valor blue, como mep y ccl están extraídos de una lista por su índice. El código para los tres tiene esta forma:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
pagina_principal_bs4 = soup.find_all("table")
#print("Number of tables on site: ",len(pagina_principal_bs4))

tabla = pagina_principal_bs4

text = []
for row in tabla[0].find_all("tr"): 
    for cell in row.find_all("td"):
        text.append(cell.get_text().strip())

valor_mep = text[10]
```

Se les ocurre alguna solución? Puede ser por excel o por python, es indistinto

Comment: Propongo que utilices pandas que te permite especificar el tipo de dato

Comment: Originalmente lo plantee con pandas, pero al grabar el archivo usando df.to_excel se sobreescriben los datos y necesito que cada vez que corra el código se agregue un dato nuevo pero sin borrar los anteriores

Comment: especifica el modo como `a` que significa append donde se agregan los datos y no se sobreescribe

Comment: Puedes ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/470466/183782) que te será de ayuda

Answer (score 4):

La solución que encontré fue convertir a "float" los datos antes de incorporarlos al excel. Al estar separados los decimales por coma y no por punto, no lo interpretaba correctamente. El código quedó:

```
valor_mep = text[10]
valor_mep = valor_mep.replace(",",".")
valor_mep = float(valor_mep)
```

Comment: En una sola línea `valor_mep = float(text[10].replace(",","."))` ;)