# ¿Es posible realizar un almacenamiento histórico de datos en Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Buenas noches estimada comunidad de programadores, Soy estudiante del lenguaje Python y me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar con su experiencia. Estoy creando un programa que sirva para contar monedas y billetes de una caja. hasta el momento he logrado desarrollar el código, pero tengo una duda con el almacenamiento de datos.

En mi proyecto, deseo que el usuario registre la fecha del arqueo de caja, la cantidad de monedas de determinado valor y billetes y deje un registro en una hoja excel. Sin embargo, deseo que cada vez que el usuario ingrese, el programa anexe hacia abajo la nueva información, respetando las filas y las columnas del DF creado con anterioridad:

[image: aqui el programa creo el excel llamado "prueba" el cual es un DF de la info que deseo guarde, en amarillo esta lo que intento que realice pero no he podido. cada vez que el programa se ejecuta el reemplaza, pero quiero que acumule hacia abajo que es la zona amarilla y por ejemplo la fecha del nuevo arqueo]

Les comparto el código que tengo actualmente:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import ExcelWriter

print(" bienvenido al sistema de conteo de caja")
FECHA=input("Por favor coloque la fecha del cuadre AAAA/MM/DD: ")
while True:

print("""que deseas hacer? 
      1. registrar valores
      2. calular valores
      3. Generar reporte de caja
      4. crear archivo de excel para analisis
      5. generar valores de ajuste de saldo
      6. borrar o modificar datos ingresados
      8. terminar el programa""")
opcion=input()
if opcion=="1":
    moneda_1=float(input("cantidad moneda de 50 "))
    moneda_2=float(input("cantidad moneda de 100 "))
    moneda_3=float(input("cantidad moneda de 200 "))
    moneda_4=float(input("cantidad moneda de 500 "))
    moneda_5=float(input("cantidad moneda de 1.000 "))
    billete_1=float(input("cantidad billete de 2.000 "))
    billete_2=float(input("cantidad billete de 5.000 "))
    billete_3=float(input("cantidad billete de 10.000 "))
    billete_4=float(input("cantidad billete de 20.000 "))
    billete_5=float(input("cantidad billete de 50.000 "))
    billete_6=float(input("cantidad billete de 100.000 "))
    resultado_1=moneda_1*50
    resultado_2=moneda_2*100
    resultado_3=moneda_3*200
    resultado_4=moneda_4*500
    resultado_5=moneda_5*1000
    resultado_6=billete_1*2000
    resultado_7=billete_2*5000
    resultado_8=billete_3*10000
    resultado_9=billete_4*20000
    resultado_10=billete_5*50000
    resultado_11=billete_6*100000
    #### generar lista de variables
    reporte=[resultado_1,resultado_2,resultado_3,resultado_4,resultado_5,resultado_6,resultado_7,resultado_8,resultado_9,resultado_10,resultado_11]
    suma=sum(reporte[:])
    ##genera reporte en df
    data={"Fecha":[FECHA]*len(reporte),"valor":[50,100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000,20000,50000,100000],"cantidad":[moneda_1,moneda_2,moneda_3,moneda_4,moneda_5,billete_1,billete_2,billete_3,billete_4,billete_5,billete_6],
    "total":[resultado_1, resultado_2, resultado_3, resultado_4, resultado_5, resultado_6, resultado_7, resultado_8,resultado_9,resultado_10,resultado_11]}
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
    ###df["total acumulado"]=df["total"].rolling(window=2).sum()#### validar codigo no sirve
elif opcion=="2":
    print("usted tiene en caja "+str(suma))
elif opcion=="3":
    print(df)
elif opcion=="4": ### genera archivo de reporte de caja
    escritor=pd.ExcelWriter("C:/Users/Home/´prueba.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
    df.to_excel(escritor,sheet_name="prueba1", index=False)
    escritor.save()
    print("data guardada")
elif opcion=="5":
    variable=int(input("por favor digite el saldo actual de caja: "))
    saldo=df["total"].sum()
    ajustar=print("el valor a ajustar es", saldo-variable)
    ajustar_1=saldo-variable
    if ajustar_1<=0:
        print(ajustar_1," a la cuenta del gasto de caja")
    else:
        print(ajustar_1," a la cuenta del ingreso de caja")
elif opcion=="6": ### zona en construccion
    borrar=input("que dato deseas eliminar? conteo especifico(Re) o todo(all)? ")
    if borrar=="Re":
        print("que conteo desea borrar o modificar? guiese de la columna Indice")
        seleccion=int(input("coloque el numero de indice del conteo a modificar y/o  eliminar"))
        borrar_Re=df.loc[seleccion,"cantidad"]
        print("el dato a modificar es ",borrar_Re)
        nuevo_valor=float(input("coloque el nuevo conteo: "))
        df.loc[seleccion,"cantidad"]=nuevo_valor
    else:
        print("el digito no existe en el rango")
        print("dato modificado")
elif opcion=="8":
    print("gracias por usar el sistema, vuelva pronto ")
    break
```

Me disculpo si el código es extenso, hasta ahora llevo 3 meses en el lenguaje el cual me parece maravilloso y espero convertirme en un experto y profesionalizarme en el. gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: En vez de crear 10 variables `resultado_x` iguales, te recomiendo que uses una lista... Igual con las monedas y billetes, te será más fácil manejar las variables y reducirás enormemente la cantidad de código que escribes (haciendo las asignaciones/lecturas en bucles, por ejemplo)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como puedo copiar y pegar informacion en un template de excel (que ya esta formulado y todo) mediante Python con Pandas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/470384/como-puedo-copiar-y-pegar-informacion-en-un-template-de-excel-que-ya-esta-formu)

Answer (score 0):

Python puede usar diferentes motores para trabajar con datos de excel, y el que estás usando en tu código (`xlsxwriter`), no admite agregar datos directamente en la hoja de excel.

Para hacer lo que pretendes, si quieres seguir usando ese módulo, debes leer primero los datos existentes en la hoja de excel, y volcarlos a un DataFrame, agregar los nuevos datos al DataFrame, y por último volcarlos de nuevo al fichero excel.
Es una forma engorrosa de hacer las cosas si no deseas manipular los datos existentes (para eliminar duplicados, por ejemplo).

Otra forma de hacerlo es cambiar al motor de `openpyxl`, que tiene un modificador `append`. El código sería algo así:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:
    df.to_Excel(writer, sheet_name="name", startrow=num, startcol=num)
```